# R. Error with read.table and paste(). Function is sticking FALSE from stringsAsFactors = F to object

Tags: r, paste, read.table

I have a directory in an external hard disk, Apple laptop:

```
setwd("/Volumes/HD/1000Genomes/phased_IMPUTE2")
```

I want to run a for loop with some files:

```
for(i in 1:22) {
   infile1 <-
paste("chr",i,"_cancer.impute.hap",
                sep="", stringsAsFactors = F) # 
   infile2 <- 
paste("chr",i,"_cancer.impute.legend",
                sep="", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)

   outfile <- 
paste("chr",i,"_cancer_phased.txt",sep=" ")

   hap <- read.table(infile1)
   leg <- read.table(infile2)

   # Perform more tasks...

 }
```

However, I get the following message:

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 
'chr1_cancer_impute.hapFALSE': No such file or 
directory
```

It seems the paste() function is pasting the "FALSE" of stringsAsFactors = F. I must be doing some very silly mistake. Does anybody know what it is happening?. Thanks very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `stringsAsFactor` option when you call `paste`, because the output will always be character.  Just use `paste` without it:

```
paste0("chr", 5, "_cancer.impute.hap")

[1] "chr5_cancer.impute.hap"
```

From what I see, it appears that `stringsAsFactor` is being ignored, but the `FALSE` value is then being included with the concatenation, resulting in your current output.

Comment: Thank you @Tim Biegeleisen. But what should I do if I need to use arguments such as "header = T"?

Comment: @Lucas Header? Paste doesn't take that argument either.  You seem to be conflating paste with several other functions, e.g. `read.table`.

Comment: You are absolutely right @Tim Biegeleisen. Thanks very much